# Dialog box growing with content, but not exceeding window height (without JS)

Tags: html, css

We like to integrate a dialog box into our webapplication.

We have dynamic height content and want the box to be as high as the content, **but** if the content is relatively high, we don't want to have the dialog box being higher than the window height.

In other words: **wrap the content in the dialog box, if it makes the dialogbox taller than the window**

Here is what does not work: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aClnr

Possible without JS? The problem is the dynamic height...

**Requirements:**

- I want the box to be centered horizontally and vertically
- I want a margin from the top and the bottom always (let's say 20px each)´
- I want the #contentContainer to be scrollable when it overflows, not the box (thus keeping the 20px padding)

It doesnt look nice when the `#contentBox` is scrolling over the padding of `#box`

**Don't want to have something like that:**
**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ajltx**

Comment: css: `height:auto;max-height:100%;overflow:auto;clear:both;` may help you.

Comment: -1??? Why??? Explain that!!! Otherwise it makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to this:

```
#box {  
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#contentContainer {
   padding: 20px;
}
```

Like this, the box will become as heigh as the body max. When the content overflows the window a scrollbar will appear. Here is the demo: http://codepen.io/Nico_O/pen/jIJcb

Comment: Looks good so far. But I want the box to be centered horizontally and vertically. And I want a margin from the top and the bottom always (let's say 20px each). And I want the #contentContainer to be scrollable when it overflows, not the box (thus keeping the 20px padding). I edited my question.